# How to get the placeholders that require feeds for a given tensorflow operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Consider the following tensorflow python code:

```
a, b = tf.constant(1, tf.float32), tf.constant(2, tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, ())
y = a * x + b
print(tf.Session().run(y, {x: 2}))
```

In this case, I was well aware that in order for the `run` to work, I need to feed the placeholder `{x: 2}`.

But what if I wasn't aware of what placeholders are required (probably because the graph is too complicated, or because it is hidden away in someone's function)?

In such a situation, **is it possible to dynamically obtain the list of feeds required to evaluate y**?
I am hoping for something like:

```
print(tf.feeds(y)) # [<tf.Tensor 'x:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
# Or:
print(y.feeds()) # [<tf.Tensor 'x:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
```

Comment: Maybe look at global list of variables and check for type (?).